# Passing ref's content from a child to another VueJS child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm learning VueJS and I got a little confused on the ref, $refs lecture. I tried to understand it from vue's documentation,  but I didn't get what I want to know.

If for example I have this component:

`<user-item ref="details"></user-item>`

and I get the data from this component using

this.$refs.details

to use that data in the User parent component, because this user-item is a child for User component.

```
<div id="User">
  <user-item ref="details"></user-item>
</div>
```

In the same time I have another component called, let's say Permissions that's child too, for User component:

```
<div id="User">
   <user-item ref="details"></user-item>
   <permissions></permissions> 
</div>
```

In this Permissions component I need the same  this.$refs.details, but from what I test, like an experiment, doesn't work.

This is just a simple example.

Can someone please tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't need to use `$refs` to pass data between components. Use `data`, `props` or dispatch events between components instead.

if you really want to access your `user-item` via `$refs`. Then you should do it like this from your `permissions` component.

```
this.$parent.$refs.details
```

It will basically get a reference to the parent (your `User` component) which has `details` in its `$refs`.

This assumes that your components are put together like this:

```
<user>
  <user-item ref="details"></user-item>
  <permissions></permissions>
</user>
```

**Edit:**
`$refs` seems like it's empty when the component is being mounted, therefore, `details` will be `undefined`. Passing the whole `$refs` object to the `permissions` component's `props` seems to work with the OP.

```
<user>
  <user-item ref="details"></user-item>
  <permissions :parentRefs="$refs"></permissions>
</user>
```

Where `parentRefs` is a member in `permissions` component's `props`.

OP was able to access `user-item` from `permissions` using `this.parentRefs.details`.

Comment: Kira I tried to use this.$parent.$refs.details and I got: "Cannot read property 'details' of undefined"

Comment: hmm can you post a snippet of your code? it should work fine.

Comment: `this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$parent.$ref.details.open({
            title: this.fullName,
          });
        });` this is in the child and this is in the parent: `this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$refs.details.open({
            title: this.fullName,
          });
        });`

Comment: try to console log `this.$parent` and `this.$parent.$refs`. I think that `$refs` takes some time after the component is mounted to be available. I saw this in many cases.

Comment: for this.$parent.$ref I get: `Object {backdrop: div.fullscreen.layout-backdrop.transition-generic.no-pointer-events.q-touch.q-touch-y, header: header.layout-header.transition-generic.fixed-top, main: div.layout-page-container.transition-generic, footer: ...`  and for this.$parent I get in console: `VueComponent {_uid: 11, _isVue: true, $options: Object, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent…}`

Comment: Look at my edited answer. Your layout has to be like that. You need to be sure that $parent points to the vue component that has `details` in its `$refs`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149589/discussion-between-kira-san-and-john-smith).

Comment: that list was too long to put it here and has a lot of VueComponents. Indeed my components are exactly how you put them above. Inside User I have the other 2 and user-details has that ref

Comment: just look at the `$el` in your VueComponent and `$refs`

Comment: The security soft from work doesn't let me to open the chat :(

Comment: I see in that VueComponent: `$el: div.layout`, this is from my parent

Comment: No worries. Ok, what about $refs?

Comment: I'm on chat. Please let's go there

Comment: to me this seems wrong. child components should not be relying on a chain of externalities to communicate. We need a single source of truth (maybe not a la vuex/state management, but at least an external service)